# Inserting image to SAP HANA Table using XSJS

Tags: javascript, image, sapui5, hana

I know this is a known issue but I'm having difficulty on fixing my problem. It seems that I don't receive anything from my UI5 Application when I sent an image via FileUploader to my server. I am new to HCP and this is my first time handling XSJS file. I hope you can help me.

### UI5.controller.js

```
sap.ui.define([  
"sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"  
], function(Controller) {  
"use strict";  
return Controller.extend("sample.controller.View1", {  
handleUploadPress : function(oEvent)    
{    
    var fileLoader =this.getView().byId("FileLoader");//XML View  

         var fileName = fileLoader.getValue();    
         jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.commons.MessageBox");    
           if (fileName === "" )    
             {    
                     sap.ui.commons.MessageBox.show("Please choose File.", sap.ui.commons.MessageBox.Icon.INFORMATION, "Information");    
           }    
           else    
           {    
             var uploadUrl = "https://xxxxxx/services/Sample.xsjs?file_name="+fileName;    
             var formEle = jQuery.sap.domById("UpdateContact--FileLoader");   
             var form = $(formEle).find("form")[0] ;    
             var fd = new FormData(form);       
             $.ajax({    
                       url: uploadUrl,    
                       type: "GET",    
                       beforeSend: function(xhr)    
                       {    
                                 xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", "Fetch");    
                       },    
                       success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {    
                                 var token = XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader('X-CSRF-Token');    
                                 $.ajax({    
                                           url: uploadUrl,    
                                           type: "POST",    
                                           processData :false ,   
                                           contentType: false,  
                                           data: fd,    
                                           beforeSend: function(xhr)    
                                           {    
                                                     xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);    
                                           },    
                                           success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)     
                                           {    
                                                var resptext = XMLHttpRequest.responseText;    
                                                jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.commons.MessageBox");    
                                                sap.ui.commons.MessageBox.show(resptext, sap.ui.commons.MessageBox.Icon.INFORMATION, "Information");    
                                               if(data === "Upload successful"){  
                                                  sap.ui.commons.MessageBox.show("File uploaded.", sap.ui.commons.MessageBox.Icon.INFORMATION, "Information");    
                                               }  
                                           },    
                                           error: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)    
                                           {    
                                                     sap.ui.commons.MessageBox.show("File could not be uploaded.", sap.ui.commons.MessageBox.Icon.ERROR, "Error");    
                                           }    
                                 });    
                       }} ) ;    
              }    
         }  
       });
```

XSJS Service:

```
$.response.contentType = "text/html";    
try    
{    
    var conn = $.hdb.getConnection();    
    var filename = $.request.parameters.get("file_name");   
    var headers = $.entity.headers.length;  
    var pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO \"XXX_ASSETS\".\"XXX\" VALUES('1',?,'test',CURRENT_USER,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");   
    if($.request.entities.length > 0){    
       var file_body = $.request.entities[0].body.asArrayBuffer();    
       pstmt.setBlob(1,file_body);  
       pstmt.execute();  
       $.response.setBody("[200]:Upload successful!");    
    }    
    else    
    {    
       $.response.setBody("No Entries");    
    }    
    pstmt.close();    
    conn.commit();    
    conn.close();    

    }    
    catch(err)    
    {    
       if (pstmt !== null)    
       {    
         pstmt.close();    
       }    
       if (conn !== null)    
       {    
         conn.close();    
       }    
       $.response.setBody(err.message);    
     }   
}
```

My code was built based on the tutorials I have found on the internet. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to save the image is converting(Base64) and save as blob in HANA table.

Regards